# How to add products grid in Edit/new form

Tags: magento-2.1, grid, forms

I am working on an extension where i want to load **products grid serializer** inside form.
I followed **magento_catalog** and adding below code in my **ui_component** form.

```
<fieldset name="assign_products">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products in Category</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="assign_products_container" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\AssignProducts</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

but getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   getProductsReadonly() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\m22\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product.php:137

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
      <block class="<vendor_name>\<module_name>\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\AssignedProduct" name="promo_catalog_edit_tab_affected" >
        <arguments>
            <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products in Category</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
```

Comment: this is not working